# Android - Store data in Array of Objects and display later in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have two activities in my tab-bar application. One activity (activity1) is a normal activity and the other (activity2) is a ListActivity. In activity1, there is a button which stores every time I tap on the button data (date, value1,value2..) in an array of objects. I read that this is possible with Intents. But I dont want to start activity2 everytime I tap on the button.

How can I pass the array to activity2, so I can display them later after I tapped more than once on the button in my ListView?

**EDIT :**

Here is my code. But I get a NullPointerException, so it doesn't store correctly. My Object hat Serializable implemented.

**Activity1:**

```
     Intent datenIntent = new Intent(this, LoggerActivity.class);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putSerializable("Daten",aDatensatz);
     datenIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**Activity2:**

```
Bundle bundleData = this.getIntent().getExtras();
Datensatz[] aDatensatz = (Datensatz[]) bundleData.getSerializable("Daten");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array in one shot from one activity to another in the following way :

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, array);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(myBundle);
```

And for receiveing

You can retrieve the value in another activity in following way:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array = b.getStringArray(key);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it simple for you. Removed serialization. Please have a look at it.

Comment: but my array is not a string array. its an Object array. does this matter?